# iPhone Application Local or Remote Database

Tags: iphone

I am planning to write an iPhone app and I am weighing in the options to either make the database local (on the device) or host on my server and access it through web services. What are the advantages/disadvantages of these two different approaches?

Comment: you could also consider CoreData with iCloud.

Comment: but iCloud is basically on the device, with regular copies to apple sevrvers

Comment: If the database is on the device then users can only receive updates when I push an update for the app. If the database is on the server then I can simply update the database and people will get the changes.

Comment: yes but what if the user want to use your app when is on the plain?

Comment: @alinoz That is also true! :) In other works user MUST have internet access if the database is not local.

Comment: I'm planing an app where i have a similar problem like yours. O was considering a kind of autoupdate of the local db when the user is coming online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

advantages of a local database

- alwayws avaliable (also with no networkconnection)
- fast because you don't need a networkconnection
- secure because the data won't fly over the net

disadvantages of a local database

- remotely change values (you cant change uservalues)
- no statistical overview